# Strcmp comparing to identical strings but not entering loop

Tags: c, arduino

```
char* timecompare(){
    char time[8];
    snprintf(time,8,"%i:%02i",hour(),minute());
    return time;
}

char* timefeed = "8:0";

if (strcmp(timecompare(), timefeed) == 0){
    Serial.println("hello"); 
}
```

I have this as my code when timecompare() and timefeed are both equal it is not printing hello? I this a pointer problem?  I instead of comparing timecompare() with timefeed I compare timecompare() with "8:0" then the loop works... Is this a problem with the timefeed variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a stack allocated variable, `time`, from `timecompare()`. This is illegal since stack allocated memory is only valid in the function in which the variable is declared.

Instead you need to return a heap allocated string.  Your compiler should be warning you of this.  You could write it like this:

```
char* timecompare(){
    char* time = malloc(8);
    snprintf(time,8,"%i:%02i",hour(),minute());
    return time;
}
```

Remember to `free()` the memory after you are finished with it.

Comment: the malloc line gives me an error invalid conversion from void* to char*

Comment: and again I can type in a value instead of the variable timefeed and get the correct result, so isn't the problem  the timefeed variable?

Comment: Modern compilers shouldn't do that. You'll have to cast the return value from malloc `char* time = (char*) malloc(8);`

Comment: @user you can't return memory from the stack.

Comment: malloc didn't do anything its still not entering the loop

Comment: @user presumably timecompare() is thus returning something that is different from timefeed. Did you look with the debugger? Or did you just print out the two strings before you compared them?

Answer (score 1):

You return a local variable `time` out of its scope. When you exit the function `timecompare`, the returned value is no longer a valid pointer.

Also, remove the "02" from the `%02i`, it should be `%i` if you compare it to 8:0. Using `%02i` will yield "00".

Comment: if I declare time outside of everything will that fix the problem?

Comment: It will fix this problem, but might create other problems, using global variables is not a desired solution.

Comment: so what would be the best solution?  I tried the above solution but it did not work.